# React Router: Conditional redirect if not query parameter present

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I am trying to do a conditional redirect, if there is no 'state' query parameter in the url, I want to redirect to an error page.

I am trying to do it in my App.tsx. Since at this point I can not use the hook: useLocation or useHistory, I am getting the query parameter using:

```
export default function App(): JSX.Element {

  const urlQuery = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  const stateParam = urlQuery.get('state');
  ...
}
```

then:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  {!stateParam && <Redirect to="/error?state=1" />}
  <Route path="/" exact component={HomeScreen} />
  <Route path="/t1" exact component={T1Screen} />
  <Route path="/t4" exact component={T4Screen} />
  <Route path="/t2" exact component={T2Screen} />
  <Route path="/t3" exact component={T3Screen} />
  <Route path="/error" exact component={ErrorScreen} />
</BrowserRouter>
```

It's working, but:

1. is there a way to do the verification per route (without doing it inside in each screen file)?, because there are a couple new pages coming which will not need to have state param, also error screen should not need state param.
2. I would like to keep the verification in one place, either in App.tsx or in another file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Since it seems you are using `react-router-dom` v5 you can create a custom `Route` component that does this check for you and conditionally renders the routed component or a redirect.

Example:

```
import { Redirect, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const StateParamRoute = props => {
  const { search } = useLocation();
  const urlQuery = new URLSearchParams(search);
  const stateParam = urlQuery.get('state');

  return stateParam ? <Route {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/error?state=1" />;
};
```

Use the `StateParamRoute` for the routes you want this check to occur.

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <StateParamRoute path="/t1" component={T1Screen} />
    <StateParamRoute path="/t4" component={T4Screen} />
    <StateParamRoute path="/t2" component={T2Screen} />
    <StateParamRoute path="/t3" component={T3Screen} />
    <Route path="/error" component={ErrorScreen} />
    <Route path="/" component={HomeScreen} />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

### Update for `react-router-dom@6`

Use the `useSearchParams` hook to access the queryString search, and convert the custom route component into a wrapper component for use in a layout route.

```
import { Navigate, Outlet, useSearchParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const StateParamWrapper = () => {
  const [search] = useSearchParams();
  const stateParam = search.get('state');

  return stateParam ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/error?state=1" replace />;
};
```

...

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route element={<StateParamWrapper />}>
      <Route path="/t1" element={<T1Screen />} />
      <Route path="/t4" element={<T4Screen />} />
      <Route path="/t2" element={<T2Screen />} />
      <Route path="/t3" element={<T3Screen />} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/error" element={<ErrorScreen />} />
    <Route path="/" element={<HomeScreen />} />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: How about in v6?

Comment: @NolanAmy Use the [useSearchParams](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usesearchparams) hook instead of accessing the search value from the `location` object. You will, OFC, need to use the `Route` and `Navigate` components to create a layout/wrapper component to redirect since RRDv6 doesn't have a `Redirect` component and doesn't support custom route components.

Comment: @NolanAmy I've updated answer with an example RRDv6 implementation.